# Azure Devops: Developing pipeline YAML files by running locally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am struggling with my Azure DevOps pipeline and would like to see the directory structure of the build.

My current issue is with setting up testing with code coverage reporting for multiple (variable amount, prefer not to hard code) test libraries in our repositories. However, this is just the current problem so having a proper DevOps environment setup for development is my end goal.

My preferred option is to run the pipeline locally during development of the YAML script, but I haven't found a way to trigger the build without committing to the repo.

Another option could be to zip the $(Build.SourcesDirectory) and download it.

Does anyone have advice on how to troubleshoot a YAML based build? Can you share how you did it with a snippet from your YAML?

Note:
My google-fu has failed me in finding a best practice in how to approach DevOps development of pipelines. While I am an experienced developer, the nature of DevOps is new to me. I have done build servers in the past, but Azure has gotten the better of me.